# Compute the posterior density for r

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian

I'm trying to understand the posterior distribution. For a simple example if i consider the beta function with parameters $\alpha=1=\beta$. Then the prior would be uniform in the range of 0 to 1 so $p(r) = 1$. If the likelihood is binomial, since we consider an experiment with two possible outcomes, would it be correct to say that the posterior density is given by the following?
$$p(r|y) = P(y|r) p(r) = \binom{n}{y}r^y(1-r)^{n-y}\cdot 1$$
Also if anyone could point me to some good resources regarding this it would be greatly appreciated, as i find a lot of confusing stuff online regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite:

- $\binom{n}{y}r^y(1-r)^{n-y}$ may sum over $y$ to $1$ but it does not integrate over $r$ to $1$ so it is not a probability density
- more generally the posterior density is *proportional* to the prior density multiplied by the likelihood rather than being *equal* to it
- so the answer should be $\dfrac{\binom{n}{y}r^y(1-r)^{n-y}\cdot 1}{\int\limits _{r=0}^1 \binom{n}{y}r^y(1-r)^{n-y}\cdot 1\, dr}$ with some obvious cancellations; this is the density of a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=1+y,\beta=1+n-y$

Comment: Are you not allowed to omit the denominator in the answer in your post? I was under the assumption that when the prior is a beta distribution and the likelihood is a binomal distribution, then the beta is conjugate to the binomial.

Comment: @sn3jd3r  The posterior probability density function is in fact $\dfrac{r^y(1-r)^{n-y}}{B(1+y,1+n-y)}$ when $0 \le r \le 1$ where the denominator is a [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) which does not vary with $r$; this is the density of a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  If you omit this denominator then you do not have a probability density function as it will not integrate to $1$, merely something proportional to the density.